Load mixed content on page load with Javascipt
Modern browsers are constantly forcing https for all situations.
Issue: Need to load mixed content
Before the https requests were being force, I could use JS to force the page to reload as http for the camera part of the page. It's no longer working in many browsers. I have tried all of the easy basic javascript tricks but they have all failed. I'm using squarespace so I can't override the browser requests server side.
Currently, if the page loads as http: it does the following:
displays a Image from the camera over static IP: http://96.57.87.254:91/live/1/jpeg.jpg with the option to click on a button which goes to another page that loads the RTP video stream.
My only thoughts are to

Force the page down to http, but the browser ignores the protocol
and loads the page say http://google.com as https no matter what.

Use a CORS proxy for the http content parts? I am not sure how to get that to work with a static IP

Use some 3rd party webste to host it as https.


I'm hoping someone can help me solve one of these or suggest something else.
For example this fails:
<script> 
if (!(window.location.href.indexOf("squarespace") > -1) && (location.protocol == 'https:')) {
    alert("Cameras require that your browser use http connection, switching to it now");
    var URL = 'http://URL.org/'
    var httpAnchor = document.createElement('a');
    httpAnchor.href = URL;
    
    // Trigger a click on the anchor element
    httpAnchor.click();
}


</script>

This for example also fails:
    if (!(window.location.href.indexOf("squarespace") > -1) && (location.protocol == 'https:')) {
    alert("Cameras require that your browser use http connection, switching to it now");
    var URL = 'http://URL.org'
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


This cannot be resolved with JavaScript. Loading http content in an https context is a potentiall security risk to users (stolen data through an insecure connection, etc.). It only kinda works because many websites have mixed content and fixing all of them at once is of course unrealistic. If some older technology you're using doesn't offer https, a proxy would have to forward the traffic. Mozilla - mixed content: how to fix

@PeterPointer I get the reasoning for it and such but the fact that the browser refuses to point to http once it loads as https seems like overkill. If it weren't for that I would just reload the whole site as http. That is really what I'm trying to do as a workaround until I resolve a way to stream the video.

Well you can change your website so it uses links starting with // so they will be relative to the current protocol. No need for JavaScript in that case. If you rewrite a URL with JavaScript, the browser or browser console may still complain about the protocol discrepancy before JS executes.

@PeterPointer thanks but that wouldn't work because I'm in the Square Space ecosystem, the site loads https first as it sees it's available then never goes back. The one thing I am going to try if Squarespace settings allow is to link to my other domain as http:// for the same content. Right now that doesn't work because SQ space automatically loads the primary as https even if you use the secondary domain.

Ah ok sure. I don't see a JavaScript solution working. BTW others have asked similar questions independently of squarespace, but maybe the solution could be similar? SO search: webcam https access
